# Cuda GPU optimization

Tags: cuda, gpu, acceleration

i have read that there were 100X acceleration on certain problems when you use NVIDIA GPU instead of CPU.
what are the best performance acceleration timings using cuda on different problems.
please state the problem and the acceleration factor along with links for papers if possible.

Comment: Well, that totally depends on what hardware you have. Newest graphic card and oldest cpu and you will have a huge performance increase on floating point operations I guess.

Comment: i need the latest results...
on the newest GPUs

Comment: I would recommend the go with OpenCL than CUDA.

Answer (score 3):

These are a few striking examples from natural sciences:

Ab initio quantum chemistry calculation (TeraChem): up to 50x
Molecular dynamics simulations (HOOMD): up to 32x 
Molecular orbitals visualization with VMD: 20x-100x

More could be found here:
http://www.nvidia.com/object/tesla_bio_workbench.html 
Papers are to be found within the link. Unfortunately I could not show
more direct links, since my status (new account) does not permit more than
one hyperlink.
Thanks.

Comment: I would take those numbers with a grain of salt.  The most glaring omission - single precision versus double precision on CPU, which for many applications makes results suspect at best

Comment: Agreed. Not that I advocate for a single precision:  However, a general criticism has to be strengthened by concrete examples where single precision does not work. After all, the floating point addition is not an associative operation - in any parallel execution context it matters A LOT.

Comment: my background is chemistry, where accuracy must be `10^-8 `. For such applications, using single precision is a bad option in my opinion.
In some chemistry applications even double precision is not sufficient, where long recursion is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the CUDA community showcase: http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_showcase_html.html

Answer (score 0):

Gumerov was able to speed up the FMM for the Laplace Potential up to ~70x. You can read his excellent paper [here (pdf)](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/pingali/CS378/2008sp/papers/Gumerov.pdf).

However, such results are usually rather meaningless. For example, the Intel Core i7 980 XE is rated at 109GFLOPS, whereas the Nvidia GTX 480 reaches 672 GFLOPS. If both architectures are fully utilized, the maximum speedup achievable would be about 6 times. Of course, for certain problems it is easy to get a high utilization on the GPU but hard on the CPU.